# Gif Image Compressing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, skiasharp

I try to compress an image using Skiasharp but that not working for me. I can't encode the image `encodedData.SaveTo(outputStream)` which encodedData was nullable.

```
using (var inputStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\NidalMomani\Downloads\ban.gif"))
{
    using (var inputStreamWithSeek = new SKManagedStream(inputStream))
    {
        using (var originalBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(inputStreamWithSeek))
        {
            // Create a new image info with the desired compression quality
            var imageInfo = new SKImageInfo(originalBitmap.Width, originalBitmap.Height, SKColorType.Rgba8888, SKAlphaType.Premul);
            var qualityEncoder = SKWebpEncoderOptions.Default;
            qualityEncoder.Quality = 80;

            // Compress the image to a new output file
            using (var outputStream = System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\Users\NidalMomani\Downloads\compressingfiles\bannergifnew.gif"))
            {
                using (var image = SKImage.FromBitmap(originalBitmap))
                {
                    using (var encodedData = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Gif, 80))
                    {
                        encodedData.SaveTo(outputStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just because gif is not supported

Comment: "If Encode creates an empty array, it means that the particular file format isn't supported." the document related:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/saving